# Make a scrollView autoscroll with drag and drop in Android

Tags: android, android-scrollview

I searched all over, but could not find a solution.

I have a view (lets call it myView) inside a scrollview. myView is bigger than the screen. Since I'm able to get the *relative* x,y position of my finger inside myView, I would like to make the scrollView autoscroll to the top/bottom when my finger enters a certain top/bottom threshold. 
I have some ideas, namely translating the drag location to the screen position but this did not solve this problem.

thanks in advance

cheers

Answer (score 10, accepted):

All right I figured it out by myself.

First I had to extend the ScrollView class and added an interface OnScrollViewListener.

```
public class MyScrollView extends ScrollView {
    private OnScrollViewListener mListener;

    public MyScrollView(Context c, AttributeSet attrs) {
       super(c, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onScrollChanged(int l, int t, int oldl, int oldt) {
       super.onScrollChanged(l, t, oldl, oldt);
       if (mListener != null) {
           mListener.onScrollChanged((OnScrollViewListener) this);
       }
    }


    public void setOnScrollViewListener(OnScrollViewListener listener) {
       mListener = listener;
    }


    public static interface OnScrollViewListener {
       public void onScrollChanged(OnScrollViewListener listener);
    }
}
```

Next in my Activity I inserted a member mScrollDistance that indicates the amount of 
pixels the user scrolls.

```
public class ScrollActivity extends Activity {
   private int mScrollDistance;

   @Override
   protected void OnCreate(...) {
     ...

     final MyScrollView myScrollView = (MyScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scroll_view);
     myScrollView.setOnScrollViewListener(new MyScrollView.OnScrollViewListener() {

          public void onScrollChanged(OnScrollViewListener listener) {
             mScrollDistance = listener.getScrollY();
          }
     }

     // making an drag and drop in an view that is inside the MyScrollView
     final LinearLayout myLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linear_layout);
     myLayout.setOnDragListener(new View.OnDragListener() {
       public boolean onDrag (View v, DragEvent event) {
         int action = event.getAction();
         switch(action) {
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED: {
            }
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_LOCATION: {

              int y = Math.round(event.getY());
              int translatedY = y - mScrollDistance;
              int threshold = 50;
              // make a scrolling up due the y has passed the threshold
              if (translatedY < threshold) {
                 // make a scroll up by 30 px
                 myScrollView.scrollBy(0, -30);
              }
              // make a autoscrolling down due y has passed the 500 px border
              if (translatedY + threshold > 500) {
                 // make a scroll down by 30 px
                 myScrollView.scrollBy(0, 30);
              }
              // listen for more actions here
              // ...
            }
         }
       }
     }
```

Now, mScrollDistance gets always a new value and the drag location will be translated to the view location.
I tested this and it works on layouts/views that are bigger than the screen size.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, although your whole effort with the custom ScrollView is not necessary. Instead of using the custom ScrollView and listener stuff etc. to get the mScrollDistance, you can simply use the normal ScrollView's getScrollY() method when you calculate the translatedY variable.

Comment: I realized that your solution only works if there's only one element to be dragged and finally ended up with a completely different solution based on overriding the `dispatchDragEvent()` method. If anybody is interested in details, please comment here.

Comment: @Ridcully This solution is not working when we try to drag and drop downwards. Also if try to drag and drop downwards and then try to drag and drop other elements upwards, this isn't working.

It would be helpful if you can provide solutions for the same.

Answer (score 6):

I came up with a different solution and I am happy with it.

I want to be able to drag and drop views inside a ScrollView. The ScrollView then needs to scroll up and down automatically when the shadow reaches the edges of the scroll view.

I ended up with a solution that detects wether the drop zone is completely visible inside the scrollview (with a 100px margin) and adjust the scroll view otherwise.

```
@Override
public boolean onDrag(View view, DragEvent event) {

    MainWidget dropZoneView = (MainWidget) view;

    int action = event.getAction();
    switch (action) {
        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED:
        //(... other stuff happens here)
        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_LOCATION:

            ScrollView mainScrollView = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.main_scroll);

            int topOfDropZone = dropZoneView.getTop();
            int bottomOfDropZone = dropZoneView.getBottom();

            int scrollY = mainScrollView.getScrollY();
            int scrollViewHeight = mainScrollView.getMeasuredHeight();

            Log.d(LOG_TAG,"location: Scroll Y: "+ scrollY + " Scroll Y+Height: "+(scrollY + scrollViewHeight));
            Log.d(LOG_TAG," top: "+ topOfDropZone +" bottom: "+bottomOfDropZone);

            if (bottomOfDropZone > (scrollY + scrollViewHeight - 100))
                mainScrollView.smoothScrollBy(0, 30);

            if (topOfDropZone < (scrollY + 100))
                mainScrollView.smoothScrollBy(0, -30);

            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for solution but in my case its works only with up scroll. not working in bottom auto scroll can you help me for same.

Comment: This solution is from 7 yrs ago. I haven't done much with native Android since and have moved from this project a looong time ago. So... no... sorry that it's not working for you.

Comment: Works great both ways almost 10 years later...

Answer (score 1):

I used a timer in In C#

```
ScrollCalendar ScrollCalendar = new ScrollCalendar (yourScrollView);
```

Inside the drag event

```
    public bool OnDrag (View v, DragEvent e)
    {
        var dragshadow = new EventDateDragShadow (v);
        switch (e.Action) {
        case DragAction.Started:
            return true;
        case DragAction.Entered:
            break;
        case Android.Views.DragAction.Location:

            if (e.GetY () < 90) {
                ScrollCalendar.StartScroll (-15);
            } else if (e.GetY () > yourScrollView.Height - 90) {
                ScrollCalendar.StartScroll (15);
            } else
                ScrollCalendar.StopScroll ();

            return (true);
        case DragAction.Exited:
            return true;
        case DragAction.Drop:
            return true;
        case DragAction.Ended:
            ScrollCalendar.StopScroll ();
            v.SetOnDragListener (null);
            return true;
        }

        return true;
    }
```

The ScrollCalendar class

```
public class ScrollCalendar
{
    private ScrollView Calendar;
    private System.Timers.Timer Timer;
    private int ScrollDistance;

    public ScrollCalendar(ScrollView calendar)
    {
        Calendar = calendar;
        Timer = new System.Timers.Timer();
        Timer.Elapsed+=new ElapsedEventHandler(Scroll);
        Timer.Interval = 50;
    }

    public void StartScroll(int scrollDistance)
    {
        if (Timer.Enabled) {
            return;
        }
        ScrollDistance = scrollDistance;
        Timer.Enabled = true;
    }

    public void StopScroll()
    {
        Timer.Enabled = false;
    }

    private void Scroll(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        Calendar.SmoothScrollBy (0, ScrollDistance);
    }

}
```

Change the StartScroll value and the Timer.Interval to adjust the speed of the scroll.

Answer (score 0):

I have modified answer of Tiago A.
I faced the same problem and the solution from Tiago A was small and easy but have some limitation so if others require this may help.
Thanks to Tiago A.

```
case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_LOCATION:
                    ScrollView myScrollView =findViewById(R.id.myScrollView);
                    int topOfDropZone = myScrollView.getChildAt(0).getTop();
                    int bottomOfDropZone = myScrollView.getChildAt(0).getBottom();

                    int scrollY = myScrollView.getScrollY();
                    int scrollViewHeight = myScrollView.getMeasuredHeight();

                    if (Math.round(event.getY()) > scrollViewHeight - (scrollViewHeight / 45))
                        if (bottomOfDropZone > (scrollY + scrollViewHeight - 100))
                            myScrollView.smoothScrollBy(0, 30);

                    if (Math.round(event.getY()) < (scrollViewHeight / 45))
                        if (topOfDropZone < (scrollY + 100))
                            myScrollView.smoothScrollBy(0, -30);

                    return true;
```

Comment: Can you add more details please, such as what is the limitation? What was your solution?